# Polar of a point with respect to a circle does not depend on the secants chosen to draw it.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, geometric-transformation

[image]

Consider a circle and a point. To find the polar we draw any two secants and find the diagonal points. Then the polar is the line joining other 2 diagonal points. This is the projective definition of a polar. But how do we know that the polar of the red point is independent of the 2 secants/chords chosen to draw it? Proving this for a circle will be enough to show that its true for a general conic because collinearity and concurrence are preserved in a projective transformation.

Comment: That’s not the definition of the polar that I learned. Be that as it may, the configuration brings to mind Pappus' theorem. That’s where I’d start.

Comment: @amd This is the projective definition, and is much better  than the definition to draw tangents at end points of a chord and the locus of the intersection of the tangents. one useful application of this definition is that we can contruct tangents to a given circle using only a straight edge. Keeping this aside, could you explain your idea a little more?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following figure where the line $p=QG$ is the polar of $P$ respect to the conic obtained with the blue quadrilater $ABCD$.
Let $IJEF$ a second quarilater and let $K=p\cap IJ$ and $H=p\cap EF$.
[image]
Note that the lines $QA$, $QB$, $QP$ and $QG$ form an harmonic group.

> **Desargues' Involution Theorem.** The points of intersection of a line with the three pairs of opposite sides of a complete quadrilateral and a conic section circumscribed about the quadrilateral form four pairs of an involution.

By [Desargues' Involution Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/ButterflyProjective.shtml), applied to the quadrilater $ACDB$ and the line $EF $, there exists one and only one involution such that $E\leftrightarrow F$, $P\leftrightarrow P$ and $QA\cap EF\leftrightarrow QB\cap EF$.
Projecting from $Q$, we get a unique involution such that $QE\leftrightarrow QF$, $QA\leftrightarrow QB$ and $QP\leftrightarrow QP$.
Since the group $QA$, $QB$, $QP$, $QG$ is harmonic, this involution fixes $QG$.
Consequently, the group $QP$, $QH$, $QE$, $QF$ is harmonic and hence $PHEF$ is harmonic.
Similarly, by considering the line $IJ $, instead of $EF $, the group $PKIJ$ is harmonic as well.

Since the group $LP$, $LM$, $LE$, $LF$ is harmonic, we must to have $LM=HK=p$, thus proving that $p$ doesn't depends on the choice of the quadrilater.

Comment: I have a bit of a problem seeing how quadrilateral $ADCB$ allows a statement about $QE\leftrightangle QF$. And I also don't see where you are using the fact that $ABCDEFIJ$ are on the same conic, which should be relevant here. Maybe these two things I don't understand are related; I don't have much experience with that Involution Theorem either.

Comment: @MgV: I add the statement of Desargue theorem and some explanation. Do you get it now?

Comment: @FabioLucchini I found a way using Pascal's theorem and Desargues' theorem :). Could you tell me some good resources to learn projective geometry?

Comment: I learn projective geometry on F. Enriques, Lezioni di geometria proiettiva.

Comment: Ah, this is a different theorem than what I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)#Projective_geometry, and it has the link to the conic section I had been missing. That helps. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that the points $I,J,K,L$ are collinear.
[image]
For that, we construct some extra points, $M=(AZ)(CX)$ and $N=(AC)(XZ)$.
[image]
Now we see that $A,B,C,X,Y,Z$ are 6 points on a conic and thus we can apply Pascal's theorem!
$$J=(AY)(BX) ,\quad K=(BZ)(CY) \quad \text{and} \quad M=(CX)(AZ) \quad \text{are collinear}$$
Applying it once more,
$$I=(AB)(XY) ,\quad L=(BC)(YZ) \quad \text{and} \quad M=(CX)(AZ) \quad \text{are collinear}$$
We also see that $\bigtriangleup ABC$ and $\bigtriangleup XYZ$ have a center of perspectivity at $P$, so by applying Desargues' Theorem, we get
$$I=(AB)(XY) ,\quad L=(BC)(YZ) \quad \text{and} \quad N=(CA)(ZX) \quad \text{are collinear}$$
But the triangles, $\bigtriangleup AYC$ and $\bigtriangleup XBZ$ also have a center of perspectivity at $P$, and thus we can apply Desargues theorem again.
$$J=(AY)(BX) ,\quad K=(BZ)(CY) \quad \text{and} \quad N=(CA)(ZX) \quad \text{are collinear}$$
Combinig these results, we get,
$$J,K,M,N\quad \text{and}\quad I,L,M,N\quad \text{are collinear}$$
Finally,
$$I,J,K,L,M,N \quad \text{are collinear}$$

Comment: Note that the two quadrilaters have a common side. Can you extends the proof in the case of two generic quadrilaters?

Comment: This was sufficient to prove. Lets call the PA,PB,PC as a,b,c. The answer shows that polar found using a,b is same as that is found using b,c and c,a. You can further say that, if there was another chord, say PD=d then the polars found using (a,b)(a,c)(a,d)(b,c)(b,d)(c,d) are all same. So as i said, this was sufficient. (The only problem I faced with your answer was that it used some heavy mathematics, I am a newbie at projective geometry and this was much easier to understand)